# Guardar dados em ficheiro excel atraves do Outlook

Tags: regex, microsoft-excel, vba

Criei uma *Rule*, que sempre que chega um email com um determinado texto no *subject* executa uma *scrip*, que tem como função percorrer todo o email e guardar determinados dados numa folha Excel.

*Código:*

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub CopyToExcelMacro()
 Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim vText, vText2, vText3, vText4, vText5, vText6, vText7, vText8, vText9 As Variant
 Dim sText As String
 Dim texto As String
 Dim rCount As Long
 Dim rValue As Integer
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim strPath As String


enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 strPath = enviro & "\Documents\Fieldanalysis.xlsx"

 Dim Ret
     Do
    Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(strPath)

    If Ret = True Then
        MsgBox "File is open Deve fechar os ficheiro excel"
    Else
        MsgBox "File is Closed"
    End If
    Loop While Ret = True

     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Fieldanalysis")
    ' Process the message record
    Set olItem = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = xlSheet.Range("D" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
     'rValue = xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount - 1).Value
     'rValue = rValue + 1
     rCount = rCount + 1


    sText = olItem.Body

    Dim Reg1 As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match

    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim testSubject As String

    Dim i As Integer


    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    ' \s* = invisible spaces
    ' \d* = match digits
    ' \w* = match alphanumeric


For i = 1 To 9

With Reg1
    Select Case i
    Case 1
        .Pattern = "(Complain. Cust.:+\s*\n*(\w*)\s*)"
        .Global = False

    Case 2
        .Pattern = "(Part number:+\s*\n*(\w*)\s*)"
        .Global = False


    Case 3
        .Pattern = "(QC-Number:+\s*\n*(\w*\d*)\s*)"
        .Global = False

    Case 4
        .Pattern = "(Manufact. date:+\s*\n*(\w*/\w*/\w*)\s*)"
        .Global = False

    Case 5
        .Pattern = "(Analysis Result+\s*\n*([\w*\s*]*)\s*)"
        .Global = False

    Case 6
        .Pattern = "(Cause text:+\s*\n*(\w*\s*\w*)\s*)"
        .Global = False

    Case 7
        .Pattern = "(Supplier name:+\s*\n*(\w*)\s*)"
        .Global = False

    Case 8
        .Pattern = "(Part number:+\s*\n*([\d]{4}\.[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3})\s*)"
        .Global = False

    Case 9
        .Pattern = "(Mileage \(Km\):+\s*\n*(\w*)\s*)"
        .Global = False

    End Select
    End With


    If Reg1.test(sText) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
        For Each M In M1
            Debug.Print M.SubMatches(1)
            strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)

        Select Case i
            Case 1
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText = strSubject

            Case 2
                'vText2 = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText2 = strSubject

            Case 3
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText3 = strSubject
                'vText3 = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))

            Case 4
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText4 = strSubject
                'vText4 = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))

            Case 5
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText5 = strSubject
                'vText5 = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
            Case 6
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText6 = strSubject

            Case 7
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText7 = strSubject

            Case 8
                'vText2 = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText8 = strSubject

            Case 9
                strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
                strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
                'vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                vText9 = strSubject
                'vText3 = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))

        End Select
        Next M
     End If

         'strSubject = Replace(strSubject, Chr(13), "")
         'testSubject = testSubject & "; " & Trim(strSubject)
         'Debug.Print i & testSubject

         'Next




Next i



  'xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = rValue
  xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = vText
  xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = vText2
  xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = vText3
  xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = vText4
  xlSheet.Range("H" & rCount) = vText5
  xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = vText6
  xlSheet.Range("J" & rCount) = vText7
  xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = vText8
  xlSheet.Range("L" & rCount) = vText9

    Call MsgBox("Foi guardado no ficheiro excel: " & vbLf & "Complain. Cust: " & vText & vbLf & " Part number: " & vText2 & vbLf & " QC-Number: " & vText3 & vbLf & " Manufact. date: " & vText4 & vbLf & " Analysis Result: " & vText5 & vbLf & " Cause text: " & vText6 & vbLf & " Supplier name: " & vText7 & vbLf & " Part number: " & vText8 & vbLf & " Mileage (Km): " & vText9)
     xlWB.Close 1
     If bXStarted Then
         xlApp.Quit
     End If

     Set xlApp = Nothing
     Set xlWB = Nothing
     Set xlSheet = Nothing
 End Sub

 Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

**Problema:**

As vezes a scrip funciona mas não consegue apanhar os dados, **Mas** se voltar a renviar o email para mim mesmo ela já funciona.

Alguém consegue identificar algum problema? penso eu que deve ser na declaração de alguma variável ou no fim do programa quando tenho de encerrar as variáveis(isto é a minha opinião) Porquê:

- A rule é sempre executa quando chega o email(mas as vezes nao apanha
  os dados que pretendo)

  ->Logo nao pode ser problema de o email chegar com um *subject* diferente
- Não pode ser problemas do `REGEX` porque se o email que recebi não
  funcionou se voltar a reenviar para mim funciona

*Como nunca programei em `VBA` não tenho a certeza se inicio/encerro as variáveis corretamente, por isso pensar que o problema vem dai.*

Comment: você já tentou colocar um ponto de interrupção no começo do seu código para depurá-lo? A *rule* que você criou é para chamar o método `CopyToExcelMacro` assim que receber um e-mail de seu interesse? Já tentou colocar somente uma mensagem nesse método para ver se ele sempre é executado ao receber o e-mail de interesse?